# Unintelligible compilation error for a simple X3 grammar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I have a quite simple grammar I try to implement using boost spirit x3, without success.

It does not compile, and due to all the templates and complex concepts used in the library (I know, it is rather a "header"), the compilation error message is way too long to be intelligible.

I tried to comment part of the code in order narrow down the culprit, without success as it comes down to several parts, for which I don't see any error anyway.

**Edit2**: the first error message is in indeed in `push_front_impl.hpp` highlighting that:
`::REQUESTED_PUSH_FRONT_SPECIALISATION_FOR_SEQUENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST::*`

I suspect the keyword `auto` or maybe the `p2` statement with `ulong_long`...but with no faith.
Need the help of you guys...spirit's elites !

Below a minimal code snippet reproducing the compilation error.
**Edit**: using boost 1.70 and visual studio 2019 v16.1.6

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp"

int main(void)
{
       std::string input = \
             "\"nodes\":{ {\"type\":\"bb\", \"id\" : 123456567, \"label\" : \"0x12023049\"}," \
                         "{\"type\":\"bb\", \"id\" : 123123123, \"label\" : \"0x01223234\"}," \
                         "{\"type\":\"ib\", \"id\" : 223092343, \"label\" : \"0x03020343\"}}";
       std::istringstream iss(input);
       namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
       using x3::char_;
       using x3::ulong_long;
       using x3::lit;
 
       auto q = lit('\"'); /* q => quote */
 
       auto p1 = q >> lit("type") >> q >> lit(':') >> q >> (lit("bb") | lit("ib")) >> q;
       auto p2 = q >> lit("id") >> q >> lit(':') >> ulong_long;
       auto p3 = q >> lit("label") >> q >> lit(':') >> q >> (+x3::alpha) >> q;
       auto node =  lit('{') >> p1 >> lit(',') >> p2 >> lit(',') >> p3 >> lit('}');
       auto nodes = q >> lit("nodes") >> q >> lit(':') >> lit('{') >> node % lit(',') >> lit('}');
 
       boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(iss >> std::noskipws), l{};
       bool b = x3::phrase_parse(f, l, nodes, x3::space);
 
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, tried multiple Boost versions, including develop branch.

Comment: The first error I see is [this assert in boost::mpl::push_front_impl](https://github.com/boostorg/mpl/blob/273db7926616f5f4d98121952d3221af6b4fc049/include/boost/mpl/aux_/push_front_impl.hpp#L38-L45): "if you've got an assert here, you are requesting a 'push_front' specialization that doesn't exist." where T = boost::mpl::aux::vector_tag<20>. Is that the same as you see? Please edit in at least some indication of the error you're getting.

Comment: @Rup on what platform/versions do you see it? This could be like a header-inclusion omission for a specific platform

Comment: @sehe Windows 10, recent VS 2019 (16.6.2, a few versions higher than the OP) with the default Windows SDK that VS2019 installs 10.0.18362.0, and Boost 1.70.0 to match OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an known MPL limitation ([Issue with X3 and MS VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900932/issue-with-x3-and-ms-vs2017), https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/515) + bug/difference of implementation for MSVC/ICC compilers (https://github.com/boostorg/mpl/issues/43).

I rewrote an offending part without using MPL  (https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/607), it will be released in Boost 1.74, until then you should be able to workaround with:

```
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE 50
```

Alternatively you could wrap different parts of your grammar into rules, what will reduce sequence parser chain.

---

Note that `q >> lit("x") >> q >> lit(':') >> ...` probably is not what you really want, it (with a skipper) will allow `" x ":` to be parsed. If you do not want that use simply `lit("\"x\"") >> lit(':') >> ...`

Comment: Hah. I wasn't far off :) Interesting that this was platform specific. +1

Comment: The two defines do not solve the issue though. I will try with newer versions of Boost and Visual Studio

Comment: You should be doing something wrong. https://godbolt.org/z/MEnGvr vs https://godbolt.org/z/8zdnzb

Comment: Not much luck with boost 1.73 and visual studio v16.6.5 (SDK: 10.0.17763.0)

Comment: The repro with prepended defines, spelled as in https://godbolt.org/z/8zdnzb, does work for me using Boost 1.73 and Visual Studio v16.6.5.

Comment: Did not put them before the includes, that should explain it. And ok for the spaces between the quotes and the quoted word.

Comment: Indeed, with the two defines suggested in your answer and placed before the headers,  compilation works.

Answer (score 2):

There's a chance that there might be a missing indirect include for your specific platform/version (if I had to guess it might be caused by using the istream iterator support header from Qi).

If that's not the issue, my attention is drawn by the `where T = boost::mpl::aux::vector_tag<20>` (/HT [@Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080719/unintelligible-compilation-error-for-a-simple-x3-grammar/63155047#comment111638901_63080719) - number 20 seems suspiciously like it might be some kind of limit.

Either we can find what trips the limit and see if we can raise it, but I'll do the "unscientific" approach in the interest of helping you along with the parser.

#### Simplifying The Expressions

I see a lot (**lot**) of `lit()` nodes in your parser expressions that you don't need. I suspect all the quoted constructs need to be lexemes, and instead of painstakingly repeating the quote symbol all over the place, perhaps package it as follows:

```
auto q = [](auto p) { return x3::lexeme['"' >> x3::as_parser(p) >> '"']; };
auto type  = q("type")  >> ':' >> q(bb_ib);
auto id    = q("id")    >> ':' >> x3::ulong_long;
auto label = q("label") >> ':' >> q(+x3::alnum);
```

Notes:

- I improved the naming so it's more natural to read:

  ```
  auto node = '{' >> type >> ',' >> id >> ',' >> label >> '}';
  ```
- I changed `alpha` to `alnum` so it would actually match your sample input
- Hypothesis: The expressions are structurally simplified to be more hierarchical - the sequences consist of fewer `>>`-ed terms - the hope is that this removes a potential `mpl::vector` size limit.

There's one missing piece, `bb_ib` that I left out because it changes when you want to actually assign parsed values to attributes. Let's do that:

#### Attributes

```
struct Node {
    enum Type { bb, ib } type;
    uint64_t id;
    std::string label;
};
```

As you can see I opted for an enum to represent `type`. The most natural way to parse that would be using `symbols<>`

```
struct bb_ib_sym : x3::symbols<Node::Type> {
    bb_ib_sym() { this->add("bb", Node::bb)("ib", Node::ib); }
} bb_ib;
```

Now you can parse into a vector of `Node`:

### Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c10b5ff7f0c5e01)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Node {
    enum Type { bb, ib } type;
    uint64_t id;
    std::string label;
};

namespace { // debug output
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node::Type t) {
        switch (t) {
            case Node::bb: return os << "bb";
            case Node::ib: return os << "ib";
        }
        return os << "?";
    }
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node const& n) {
        return os << "Node{" << n.type << ", " << n.id << ", " << std::quoted(n.label) << "}";
    }
}

// attribute propagation
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Node, type, id, label)

int main() {
    std::string input = R"("nodes": {
    {
        "type": "bb",
        "id": 123456567,
        "label": "0x12023049"
    },
    {
        "type": "bb",
        "id": 123123123,
        "label": "0x01223234"
    },
    {
        "type": "ib",
        "id": 223092343,
        "label": "0x03020343"
    }
})";

    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    struct bb_ib_sym : x3::symbols<Node::Type> {
        bb_ib_sym() { this->add("bb", Node::bb)("ib", Node::ib); }
    } bb_ib;

    auto q = [](auto p) { return x3::lexeme['"' >> x3::as_parser(p) >> '"']; };
    auto type  = q("type")  >> ':' >> q(bb_ib);
    auto id    = q("id")    >> ':' >> x3::ulong_long;
    auto label = q("label") >> ':' >> q(+x3::alnum);
    auto node
        = x3::rule<Node, Node> {"node"}
        = '{' >> type >> ',' >> id >> ',' >> label >> '}';
    auto nodes = q("nodes") >> ':' >> '{' >> node % ',' >> '}';

    std::vector<Node> parsed;
    auto f = begin(input);
    auto l = end(input);
    if (x3::phrase_parse(f, l, nodes, x3::space, parsed)) {
        for (Node& node : parsed) {
            std::cout << node << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Node{bb, 123456567, "0x12023049"}
Node{bb, 123123123, "0x01223234"}
Node{ib, 223092343, "0x03020343"}
```

Comment: For fun [I'm exercising with libfmt instead of ostream](https://godbolt.org/z/rbMK4e)

Comment: You never regret to spend time writing a good question on spirit/x3. You always get ten times more ! Thanks.

Comment: indeed, packaging quotes is the way to go. Though it was not evident for me how to do it and preferred to have a working exemple first. I will go that way.

Comment: In the fine manual, it is said that you should use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINES() to link rules declarations with their definitions. But with `auto node= x3::rules<Node,Node> {"node"} = parser_expression` it seems you use the '=' operator instead. Is that a new way of writing rules ?

Comment: @Heyji I'm pretty sure (?) the manual also mentions why you would want to do this (to tie a parser definition to a rule declaration by the type ID). This is only relevant when 1. separating rules definitions across [TU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))s 2. recursive rules

Comment: I personally dislike the macro machinery - it's very error prone and "magical" and restricts the iterator and context types. There are epic [linker error hunts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spirit-x3+unresolved) due to these. My take is that Spirit shines for small, rapid parsers which are easily unit tested, contained in a TU. So, yeah, I dodge the macros whenever I can :)